# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Unable to upload excel file again once it is uploaded recently

```
 string OleDBconstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";            
            OleDbConnection OleDBcon = new OleDbConnection(OleDBconstring + "");
            OleDBcon.Open();`enter code here`
            DataTable objSheetNmDt = OleDBcon.GetSchema("Tables");

            DataTable objExcelDt;
            objExcelDt = new DataTable();
            string sqlquery = "Select * From  [" + objSheetNmDt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]";//[{0}]                   
            OleDbCommand objCm`enter code here`d = new OleDbCommand(sqlquery, OleDBcon);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = objCmd;
            da.Fill(objExcelDt);
```

Comment: Do you have the excel file open using Excel?

Comment: Can you use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to look up the file handle and see what process is using it, and then add that to your question?

Comment: it could be as simple as its being virus scanned

Comment: Try to use using statement on every disposable part. This way you will overcome "being used" problem